# My text says$ \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{pmatrix}:a\ne0,a\in\mathbb R\right\}$ forms a group under matrix multiplication.

Tags: group-theory

My text says$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&a\\a&a\end{pmatrix}:a\ne0,a\in\mathbb R\right\}$$ forms a group under matrix multiplication.

But I can see $I\notin$ the set and so not a group.

Am I right?

Comment: There is still an identity element, although it is not the one you would expect, as you rightly point out. This shows that it is not a subgroup of the real (invertible) matrices. It should also be noted that matrices in this group are not even in the group of invertible real matrices as they all have determinant zero, and so are not invertible to the usual identity matrix.

Answer (score 23):

The identity element in this group is $\pmatrix{\tfrac12&\tfrac12\\ \tfrac12&\tfrac12}$, not $I_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I get it.

Answer (score 13):

Call that matrix $(a)$ and you get $(a)(b)=(2ab)$ thus it's closed under multiplication and $(1/2)$ is its unit.

Comment: What's more, this should be enough to give you an isomorphism between this group and $\mathbb{R}^\times$.  (Hint: consider a map $f_\gamma:G\to\mathbb{R}^\times$ given by $f_\gamma(M_a)= \gamma\cdot a$.  Can you find a $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f_\gamma(M_a)\cdot f_\gamma(M_b) = f_\gamma(M_a\circ M_b)$, where $\cdot$ is multiplication on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\circ$ is the multiplication in $G$?)

Answer (score 8):

It's important to note that this set of matrices forms a group but it does NOT form a subgroup of the matrix group $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ (the group we are most familiar with as being a matrix group - the group of invertible $2\times 2$ matrices) as no elements in this set have non-zero determinant. In particular, we are looking at a subset of $Mat(\mathbb{R},2)$ which is disjoint from $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

The identity of the group will then be the matrix $\pmatrix{\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}}$ and the inverse of the element $\pmatrix{a&a\\ a&a}$ will be $\dfrac{1}{4}\pmatrix{a^{-1}&a^{-1}\\ a^{-1}&a^{-1}}$ (you should check this).

Comment: Sir, Beutiful answer. Thanks specially for pointing out that, it is not subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 6):

If the structure be a group so it has an identity element, so for any matrix called $A$ we have: $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}
  a & a \\
 a & a \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$ for some $a\neq 1$ and if $$\text{id}_G=\begin{pmatrix}
  b & b \\
 b & b \\
  \end{pmatrix}, ~~b\neq 0$$ then $A\times\text{id}_G=\text{id}_G\times A=A$. Now $$A\times\text{id}_G=\begin{pmatrix}
  2ab & 2ab \\
 2ab & 2ab \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$ which should be equal to $A$ itself. So $a=2ab$ and since $a\neq 0$ so $b=0.5$.

Comment: Very nicely addressed!

Comment: @amWhy: Hello! Amy. Good time see you here. :-)

Comment: Hello!! $\quad \hat{\overline{\ddot\smile}}$

Comment: @BabakS. , but there is a tiny problem , if $G$ is a group and $H$ is a group such that  , $H \subset G$ then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ so $H$ contains the identity of $G$ , so the identity matrix must lie in this set of matrices whose entries are equal reals and not  zero which is wrong here !

Comment: @MathsLover: Exactly! The contradiction is arisen from this point that we assume this structure is a subset of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$. I think we should consider it independently. Like an excluded Island.

Comment: @BabakS. , so this is not a subgroup of $GL_2(R)$ ? as if it's a subgroup then the elements will have two distinct inverses , contradiction. ! , right ?